# UIWebView DiskImageCache not working correctly in iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uiwebview

I am trying to display a PDF file in a UIWebView in iOS8. This is my code:

```
func showPDF(){

    let docsDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let pdfFilePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("PDF/MobileHIG.pdf")

    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(pdfFilePath)!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

    //constraints
    webView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraints([height, width])

}
```

This works just fine in iOS7. In iOS8 the PDF is also shown, however, I'll get the following warning:

> DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory.

This happens while creating the UIWebView. It doesn't have anything to do with the NSURLRequest. Further investigation has learned me that in the 'temp' folder of the app sandbox a cache folder is made like 'DiskImageCache-UiIk6kzM', in which a cache file is created. This also happens in iOS7, but the difference is that in iOS7 it reads the contents of the created cache file, while in iOS8 a new folder with a new cache file is created. This happens every time the app is launched and a new webView is made. The result is an enormous data leak: the 'temp' folders grows and grows.

In the meanwhile, I tried to disable the UIWebView caching by implementing this code:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey:    "WebKitOfflineWebApplicationCacheEnabled")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

This didn't disable the caching because the userDefaults are overwritten as soon as the UIWebView is created. A new plist file is saved in the Library/Preferences folder in which WebKitOfflineWebApplicationCacheEnabled is set as true.

My questions:

- Is the described cache behavior normal and so what am I missing? Or is it a bug that I should file to Apple?
- Is there another option to disable UIWebView caching without disabling NSCache for the whole app?